# NServiceBus 4 and custom SagaPersister

Tags: .net, iis, nservicebus

After migrating to NServiceBus 4 (from 3.3.7 to 4.0.5) I am trying to run my custom Saga Persister. I am registering it in container (one I use in whole web application), but during application startup I get exception:

> [ComponentResolutionException: Looks like you are trying to resolve a component which depends (directly or indirectly) on component which is lifestyle is PerWebRequest. Currently executed code is not in the web request scope.Analyze your dependencies and change their lifestyles (to signletons) or their dependencies.]
>      CustomApp.Mapping.WebRequestFallingBackToCallContextScopeAccessor.GetScope(CreationContext context) in c:\tfs\Main\src\AppName2\CustomApp\CustomApp.Mapping\WebRequestFallingBackToCallContextScopeAccessor.cs:40
>      Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.GetScope(CreationContext context) +33
>      Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy) +84
>      Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden) +282
>      Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired) +35
>      Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveFromKernelByType(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) +170
>      Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) +38
>      Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateConstructorArguments(ConstructorCandidate constructor, CreationContext context) +430
>      Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext context) +52
>      Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context) +30
>      Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context, Burden burden) +27
>      Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Boolean trackedExternally) +57
>      Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy) +29
>      Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden) +282
>      Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired) +35
>      Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy) +154
>      Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy) +74
>      NServiceBus.Config.DisplayInfrastructureServicesStatus.Run() in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Config\InfrastructureServices.cs:163
>      System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action) +14013700
>      NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize() in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Configure.cs:374
>      NServiceBus.Configure.CreateBus() in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Configure.cs:307
>      CustomApp.Web.Initialization.BusInstaller.Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) in c:\tfs\Main\src\AppName2\CustomApp\CustomApp.Web\Initialization\BusInstaller.cs:56
>      Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers, DefaultComponentInstaller scope) +216
>      Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers) +124
>      CustomApp.Web.WindsorContainerProvider.GetInitializedContainer() in c:\tfs\Main\src\AppName2\CustomApp\CustomApp.Web\WindsorContainerProvider.cs:87
>      CustomApp.Web.MvcApplication.GetInitializedContainer() in c:\tfs\Main\src\AppName2\CustomApp\CustomApp.Web\Global.asax.cs:265
>      CustomApp.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\tfs\Main\src\AppName2\CustomApp\CustomApp.Web\Global.asax.cs:139
>      CustomApp.Administration.Web.Global.Application_Start() in c:\tfs\Main\src\AppName2\CustomApp\Administration\CustomApp.Administration.Web\Global.asax.cs:11

Any ideas how to resolve this issue? The same code base worked smoothly NServiceBus 3.3.7

**EDIT:**
This is how I init NSB:

```
 Configure.Serialization.Xml();
 Configure.Features.Enable<SecondLevelRetries>(); 
 Configure.Features.Enable<TimeoutManager>();
 Configure.Features.Enable<Sagas>();

 var conf = Configure.With(assemblies)
     .CustomConfigurationSource(new BusConfigSource(assemblies))
     .DefineEndpointName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndpointName"])
     .CastleWindsorBuilder(container)
     .UseTransport<Msmq>()
     .UseInMemoryTimeoutPersister()
     .PurgeOnStartup(false)
     .FileShareDataBus(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NServiceBusFileShare"])
     .UnicastBus()
     .LoadMessageHandlers()
     .MsmqSubscriptionStorage();
 conf.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<CustomSagaPersister>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
 conf.CreateBus().Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<Windows>().Install());
```

I also tried the approach with manualy adding my CustomSagaPersiter to container and without calling

```
conf.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<CustomSagaPersister>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
```

But the result is the same.

Comment: Can u provide your registration code?

Comment: Chris, I added the init code.

Comment: Please create an issue https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/new and attach a  link to a repro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of investigation, it seems that container initialization process in my application is a bit strange. The container is not fully initialized during NSB startup, thus resolve of some dependencies is not possible, what causes mentioned exception.

I workaround this problem with making my CustomSagaPersister's dependencies optional (property injection), so when CustomSagaPersister is resolved by DisplayInfrastructureServicesStatus the app does not crash (dependencies are not injected, but since we are only checking what is registered and not actually using it, this is ok).

Another workaround would be removing DisplayInfrastructureServicesStatus from NSB and custom compiling it.